# How to use the same data across all tabs in SwiftUI? (ObservableObject or EnvironmentObject)

Tags: swift, tabs, swiftui, observable, environment

Here is a very simple example of an app with 2 tabs. On both tabs I have simple custom selector for Current Month. This selector is in separate DateView.swift.

On each tab I have a Text that reads data from the selector (I will use it to filter lists on each tab).

**What I want to do:**

Changing date should work globally. After changing month on one tab, I should see this month on another tab.

How to make it work? Currently I am using ObservableObject. Did I implement it wrong? Is ObservableObject just one way binding and I need two-way binding? Should I use EnvironmentObject instead?

---

Here is the code I have so far:

**ContentView.swift**

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var selection = 0
     
        var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $selection){
                FirstTabView()
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image("first")
                            Text("First")
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                SecondTabView()
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image("second")
                            Text("Second")
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(1)
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

**FirstTabView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstTabView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var selectedMonth = SelectedDate()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                DateView(selectedMonth: selectedMonth)
                
                Text("\(selectedMonth.selectedMonth)")
                .padding()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("First Tab")
        }
    }
}

struct FirstTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FirstTabView()
    }
}
```

**SecondTabView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondTabView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var selectedMonth = SelectedDate()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                DateView(selectedMonth: selectedMonth)
                
                Text("\(selectedMonth.selectedMonth)")
                .padding()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Second Tab")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondTabView()
    }
}
```

**DateView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

class SelectedDate: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedMonth: Date = Date()
}

struct DateView: View {
    static let dateFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy MMMM")
        return formatter
    }()
    
    @ObservedObject var selectedMonth = SelectedDate()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.changeMonthBy(-1)
            }
            
            Spacer()

            Text("\(selectedMonth.selectedMonth, formatter: Self.dateFormat)")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.changeMonthBy(1)
            }
            
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5))
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
    
    func changeMonthBy(_ months: Int) {
        if let selectedMonth = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: months, to: selectedMonth.selectedMonth) {
            self.selectedMonth.selectedMonth = selectedMonth
        }
    }
}

struct DateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    struct BindingTestHolder: View {
        @State var testItem: Date = Date()
        var body: some View {
            DateView()
        }
    }
    
    static var previews: some View {
        BindingTestHolder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use EnvironmentObject instead?

Yes, if you need something *global* then `EnvironmentObject` is right choice.

So

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
 
    // declare & create here (or use below alternates)
    var selectedMonth = SelectedDate()

    // alternates 
    //@EnvironmentObject var selectedMonth: SelectedDate
    //@StateObject var selectedMonth = SelectedDate() // << Xcode12/SwiftUI2

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            FirstTabView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("first")
                        Text("First")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
            SecondTabView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("second")
                        Text("Second")
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
        } 
        // << inject here (not needed if above @EnvironmentObject is used
        .environmentObject(selectedMonth) 
    }
}
```

in tab items EnvironmentObject not needed if not used, because it is transferred through hierarchy automatically

```
struct FirstTabView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                DateView()

        // ..other code
```

```
struct SecondTabView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                DateView()

        // ..other code
```

and finally where used

```
struct DateView: View {
    
    // only declared, and will be injected here automatically
    @EnvironmentObject var selectedMonth: SelectedDate

   // .. other code
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But I have 4 questions:
1. As I am using `Text("\(selectedMonth.selectedMonth)")` on some views I needed to add `@EnvironmentObject var selectedMonth: SelectedDate` on each view, correct?  
2. Initial values of EnvironmentObject should be declared somewhere (in my case in DateView.swift) as type ObservableObject? The same if I would use ObservedObject?
3. There is no need to edit SceneDelegate anymore? I saw it in some videos for older SwiftUI versions, but your code works without it.
4. How to make Preview work with EnvironmentObject?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add line breaks to comments.

Comment: 1. yes. 2. no, it is created at outermost (either in root view as shown or even in SceneDelegate. 3. optional, can be if you need to use it in SceneDelegate as well (eg. in some callbacks, etc.) 4. use like `DateView().environmentObject(SelectedDate())`

Comment: Ad 1,3,4 - Thanks, I understand. Ad 2. This I don't understand. In ContentView there is just `var selectedMonth = SelectedDate()` and it has no SelectedDate declaration with default value to Date(). In DateView.swift I have `class SelectedDate: ObservableObject {
 @Published var selectedMonth: Date = Date()
}` When I comment out this, I get an error. Should I keep it and move this to ContentView.swift?

Comment: It looks like it was my misunderstanding of your 2. Yes, your `@Published var selectedMonth: Date = Date()` is correct and can be kept as-is. If you'd want some another date as initial, you could add to `SelectedDate` initializer, like `init(month: Date = Date()) { self.selectedMonth = month}`

Comment: Thank you. Now everything is clear to me. Thanks for the tip about init. I can change date by adding some values after Date(), right? Anyway, for my app Date() is enough right now, but it is good to know about other options. Thanks again 